# dataTable : page number not formatted properly

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am using dataTable with searching,sorting and paging. Everything is working fine except paging's formatting at the bottom of the table. I have page number in double digits which are getting out of paging box. How to format it? How to center the digits?

#### css

```
div.dataTables_paginate span>a {
       width: 18px;
       text-align: center;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Try changing width to min-width. Does that help?